# How to pass an object of custom class containing a custom list to a web service?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have to implement a simple conventional web service in VS2008 C#, which would receive an Order class object, which contains a list of Product class objects. The problem arises when I create an instance of an Order class object on the client. It is declared in the proxy and does not contain any methods, thus I have no opportunity to add Products, as List of Products is now simply a System.Array.

One method which works fine is to manually serialize into XML on the client and de-serialize in the web service. This way I would be using same class declaration which I isolated into a DLL shared between web service and client application. However, I am being told that it is possible to avoid using a shared DLL and manual serialization althogether, but I just don't understand how, i.e. how do I need to declare/define Order class and where in order for it to have methods on the client?

Currently the classes are defined as follows in the shared DLL:

```
namespace MyNS
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ProductInfo { 
        public Int32 ProductID;
        public Int32 Quantity;
        public decimal CurrPrice;

        public VE_ProductInfo() { 
            ProductID = 0;
            Quantity = 0;
            CPrice = 0;
        }

        public ProductInfo(Int32 pId, Int32 quant, decimal cprice)
        {
            ProductID = pId;
            Quantity = quant;
            CPrice = cprice;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class OrderInfo
    {
        public Int32 CustomerId = 0;

        public OrderInfo () {
            Items = new List<ProductInfo>();
        }

        [XmlArray]
        public List<ProductInfo> Items {get; set;}

        public string SpecialInstructions;

        public void AddProduct(ProductInfo pi)
        {
            Items.Add(pi);
        }
    }
}
```

This class is then used in a web service method as follows:

```
public bool CreateOrder(OrderInfo Order) {
    // some code
}
```

And it is called as follows from the client:

```
WebService.MyWebService s;

WebService.OrderInfo o = new WebService.OrderInfo();

o.CustomerId = 1;
o.Items.Add(new ProductInfo(2, 4));
o.Items.Add(new ProductInfo(1, 2, 3.95m));

checkBox1.Checked = s.CreateOrder(o);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide a default constructor and field initializers for the classes shared between the application and web service, then you can put the classes in a separate library project that both projects reference. When you add the web service reference to the application, it will generate a few proxy classes that match the data "shape" of your object, sans methods. You can delete those classes (I don't remember exactly where they are located) and add a using statement to the web service proxy class file itself to import your shared classes and they will work appropriately.

Comment: You are probably referring to Reference.cs where the proxy classes are declared/defined. Do I just delete the declarations from there, is that it, that simple? 8()

Comment: Yes, just don't delete the proxy class that was created to be able to call the web methods.

Comment: This is a truly genius solution! Works like a charm. I just commented out the Order and Product classes from Reference.cs. The classes were already serializable and had default constructors, so it just worked. I cannot yet thumb you up due to being new here, but rest assured that as soon as I can I will! Thanks a lot.

Comment: glad I could help :) I actually had to do this once, oh... 6 or 7 years ago.

Comment: Just one final question: do I have to comment out/delete classes from Reference.cs every time I update web reference? I guess so...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. I would strongly urge you to just delete them and not leave them commented out. It's not hard to retrieve them, if you ever do want them back, and it can be confusing to someone to later come across them and wonder what it was left there for.

Answer (score 1):

If your web service is a WCF one and you created a proxy for it by adding a web reference you should be able to change it by editing the refernce in Visual Studio. Right Click on it and select "Configure Service Reference" then choose a Collection type of List.

Comment: No, this one is a conventional web service in VS 2008. Now I realize I should have mentioned that, thanks for pointing out!